# Struggling in saving the Rectangle with different Stroke

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm trying to save rectangles into a list and repaint them all with different stroke thicknesses. What actually happens is that I can create many rectangles as long as I want, but those rectangles have the same stroke thickness.

---

I really need help before I try recreating the project with a new approach. I have no idea how.

Here's my code:
*Form 1 Paint Event where it redraws all shapes*

```
public void PaintAll(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Rectangle rects in d._rect)
        {
            foreach (Pen p in _penRect)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rects.X, rects.Y, rects.Width, rects.Height);
            }
        }
        foreach (Rectangle squares in d._square)
        {
            foreach (Pen p in _penSquare)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, squares.X, squares.Y, squares.Width, squares.Height);
            }
        }
        foreach (Rectangle circles in d._circle)
        {
            foreach (int x in _StrokeCircle)
            {
                Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, x);
                //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
                e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p, circles.X, circles.Y, circles.Width, circles.Height);
            }
        }
        foreach (Rectangle ellipses in d._ellipse)
        {
            foreach (int x in _StrokeEllipse)
            {
                Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, x);
                //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
                e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p, ellipses.X, ellipses.Y, ellipses.Width, ellipses.Height);
            }
        }
    }
```

*Draw Class*

```
class Draw:ShapeClass
{
    public List<Rectangle> _rect = new List<Rectangle>();
    public List<Rectangle> _square = new List<Rectangle>();
    public List<Rectangle> _circle = new List<Rectangle>();
    public List<Rectangle> _ellipse = new List<Rectangle>();
    public void DrawRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        color = new Pen(brush, Stroke);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(color, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    }
    public void DrawSquare(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        color = new Pen(brush, Stroke);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(color, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    }
    public void DrawCircle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(color, new Rectangle(x,y,width,height));
    }
    public void DrawEllipse(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(color, new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    }
    public void DrawTriangle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        tPoints = new PointF[3];
        float angle = 0;
        tPoints[0].X = x;
        tPoints[0].Y = y;
        tPoints[1].X = (float)(x + width * Math.Cos(angle));
        tPoints[1].Y = (float)(y + width * Math.Sin(angle));
        tPoints[2].X = (float)(x + width * Math.Cos(angle - Math.PI / 3));
        tPoints[2].Y = (float)(y + width * Math.Sin(angle - Math.PI / 3));

        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(color,tPoints);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your design looks a bit strange. Why are there multiple things responsible for drawing something (the same thing)? Where do the variables in e.g. `Draw.DrawRectangle()` come from? I don't think it is a good idea to rely on an object's state for such a task. But this is mostly a matter of taste. For your actual question: You draw every object with every pen. Therefore, only the thickest will be visible.

Comment: There is a shape class where I declared variables

Comment: Where are _StrokeXy defined and what do they contain? To make thinnner ones visible they need to be the last in the line.. Do you really want to pile them all? And why are the draw calls duplicated in two classes?

Comment: I need to pile them all. Different shapes with different stroke thickness.

Comment: _Different shapes with different stroke thickness._ That is not what we meant. You draw the very same shape with all elements in e.g. `_StrokeCircle`. This may be right or wrong. It makes sense if the are ordered by decending stroke and/or alpha. But if they are ordered the other way round and have no transparency it would be wrong.  - You also did not answer our other questions..